# Writing a file with only ones using IOMeter

Tags: io, storage

I dont see any useful documentation online as to how to write pattern from a file as the input for IOmeter

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Load Dynamix for storage workload generation and performance analysis.  EMC has dozens of these devices deployed, which is where I think you work.  It is a trivial matter to do this with Load Dynamix Enterprise.  If you can't find one of the appliances nearby, contact us at info@loaddynamix.com and we can get you in touch with other Load DynamiX users within EMC.

Answer (score 0):

IOMeter doesn't supports custom patterns.
You can use FIO instead.

Check the HOWTO here: 
https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/master/HOWTO

You can set pattern using "verify_patter" parameter